# MS Access 2007 - Synchronizing two databases and keeping the record with the latest timestamp

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

using Access 2007, I have a master database and several slave databases. Let's say I have  a simple table: candidates.

**In the Master DB**

```
Id ;   Name    ;   Birthday   ;   Timestamp
01 ; Henri     ; 01-01-1911   ; 01-01-2017
```

**In the Slave DB**

```
Id ;   Name    ;   Birthday   ;   Timestamp
01 ; Henry     ; 01-01-1911   ; 01-02-2017
```

What I need is, that the latest manipulated record replaces the former record in the master DB. In this example the record from the slave db would replace the record from the master db.

In my current solution I loop through the recordsets and compare the timestamps. It works, but I would like to know if there is a much more efficient and faster solution? Maybe with SQL?

Best regards

Comment: data macros or replication maybe?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav unfortunately replication doesn't work with Access 2007 anymore :-(

Comment: Will the 'master' get changed by someone? If not, and assuming you include code to alert if a user changes their system clock to an earlier time (and allow for time zones) you could try this:
(1) Get the latest timestamp from the Master; (2) Get all records from the 'Other' database where timestamp is greater.

Comment: Assuming you have a matching ID Primary key field, you could join them in a query and then update the master if the slave is later ? Not sure you need a loop for this.

Comment: If you save as 2003 BE, 2003 Replica, 2007 FE Linked to replica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Assumption

I will assume ID is the unique identifier in all databases, and that there are no IDs in the slave databases that are *not* in the master database. Otherwise you have a problem because slave1 may assign ID 7 to "Fred" but slave2 may assign ID 7 to "Thomas".

### UnionQuery

```
SELECT ID, Name, Birthday, Timestamp, 1 AS SlaveNum FROM Candidates_Slave1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, Birthday, Timestamp, 2 AS SlaveNum FROM Candidates_Slave2
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, Birthday, Timestamp, 3 AS SlaveNum FROM Candidates_Slave3
UNION ALL
...
```

Then I would write a group by query off of that union query to get each ID and its maximum timestamp.

### GroupQuery

```
SELECT ID, max(Timestamp) AS MaxTime FROM UnionQuery
```

Then join that to the UnionQuery, and take the minimum (or maximum) SlaveNum (in case multiple slaves have the same maximum timestamp).

### JoinQuery

```
SELECT GroupQuery.ID, GroupQuery.MaxTime AS Timestamp, min(UnionQuery.SlaveNum) AS SlaveNum
FROM GroupQuery INNER JOIN UnionQuery ON
    GroupQuery.ID = UnionQuery.ID AND
    GroupQuery.MaxTime = UnionQuery.Timestamp;
```

Now you can get the latest (slave) data by inner joining to UnionQuery again, and you can join to the master Candidates table and compare timestamps. Add a WHERE clause that checks for any timestamps in the master table that are less than our join query:

### FullInfoQuery

```
SELECT Candidates_Master.ID, 
    Candidates_Master.Name AS Name_Master,
    Candidates_Master.Birthday AS Birthday_Master, 
    Candidates_Master.Timestamp AS Timestamp_Master, 
    UnionQuery.Name AS Name_Slave, 
    UnionQuery.Birthday AS Birthday_Slave,
    UnionQuery.Timestamp AS Timestamp_Slave
FROM (JoinQuery INNER JOIN UnionQuery 
    ON JoinQuery.ID = UnionQuery.ID AND JoinQuery.SlaveNum = UnionQuery.SlaveNum)
INNER JOIN Candidates_Master ON JoinQuery.ID = Candidates_Master.ID
WHERE Candidates_Master.Timestamp < UnionQuery.Timestamp;
```

Finally, writing an update query can sometimes be a nuisance because strictly speaking there should not be a JOIN clause in UPDATE queries, but Access lets you sometimes. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24269023/6591527) details when you get the "this recordset is not updateable" error in Access. The ANSI way to do the update would be something like this:

### UpdateQuery

```
UPDATE Candidates_Master
SET (Name, Birthday, Timestamp) = (SELECT Name_Slave, Birthday_Slave, Timestamp_Slave FROM FullInfoQuery WHERE Candidates_Master.ID = FullInfoQuery.ID)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FullInfoQuery WHERE FullInfoQuery.ID = Candidates_Master.ID);
```

Unfortunately, Access doesn't quite support that syntax, so you'd need to run something like this:

### UpdateQuery_v2

```
UPDATE Candidates_Master
SET Name = (SELECT Name_Slave FROM FullInfoQuery WHERE Candidates_Master.ID = FullInfoQuery.ID),
Birthday = (SELECT Birthday_Slave FROM FullInfoQuery WHERE Candidates_Master.ID = FullInfoQuery.ID),
Timestamp = (SELECT Timestamp_Slave FROM FullInfoQuery WHERE Candidates_Master.ID = FullInfoQuery.ID)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FullInfoQuery WHERE FullInfoQuery.ID = Candidates_Master.ID);
```

But because that has so many correlated subqueries, it could be very slow/inefficient. Try it and see. A common alternative (for me, anyway), is to write a make table query to paste the results of FullInfoQuery into its own table, and then write an UPDATE query based on that table, for which the syntax is very easy:

### UpdateQuery_v3

```
UPDATE Candidates_Master INNER JOIN tblFullInfoQuery ON Candidates_Master.ID = tblFullInfoQuery.ID
SET Candidates_Master.Name = tblFullInfoQuery.Name_Slave,
    Candidates_Master.Birthday = tblFullInfoQuery.Birthday_Slave,
    Candidates_Master.Timestamp = tblFullInfoQuery.Timestamp_Slave
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Meanwhile I had a different solution but this seems a lot faster! Thanks a lot!!!!