# Excel data to Access DB - Get: Operation must use an updateable query Error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am working on an Excel application which allows users to enter hours work through userforms and info is stored in a Access DB. I am new to excel and access connections. I am able to connect to the database but record is not saved/created due to a run-time error at the **.Update command**.
Run-Time Error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Operation must use an updatable query.

I have searched and searched and can't find a solution to this problem.  I hope someone is able to help.  (code below)

```
Sub Export_Data_Access_TI1()

Dim dbPath As String
Dim x As Long, i As Long
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim user As String
Dim NewSht As Worksheet
Dim strQuery As String
Dim recDate As String
Dim Week_Of As String

user = Sheet1.Range("A1").Text

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

'Variables for file path and last row of data
dbPath = "H:\PROJECTS\CAI_DOT-Time Tracker\CAI_EMP_SignIn_Database.accdb"
nextrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Initialise the collection class variable
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

'Check for data
If Sheets(user).Range("A2").Value = "" Then
MsgBox " There is no data to send to MS Access"
Exit Sub
End If

cnn.Mode = adModeReadWrite
'cnn.Mode = adModeShareDenyNone
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rst.Open Source:="DATA", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
    CursorType:=adOpenKeyset, LockType:=adLockPessimistic, _
    Options:=adCmdTable
'rst.Supports (adAddNew)

x = 2  'the start row in the worksheet
Do While Len(Sheets(user).Range("A" & x).Formula) > 0

With rst

.AddNew 'create a new record

.Fields("Date") = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(user).Range("A" & x).Value
.Fields("Week_Of") = Sheets(user).Range("B" & x).Value
.Fields("Month") = Sheets(user).Range("C" & x).Value
.Fields("Name") = Sheets(user).Range("D" & x).Value
.Fields("Time_In") = Sheets(user).Range("E" & x).Value
.Fields("Time_Out") = Sheets(user).Range("F" & x).Value
.Fields("Time_In2") = Sheets(user).Range("G" & x).Value
.Fields("Time_Out2") = Sheets(user).Range("H" & x).Value
.Fields("Group") = Sheets(user).Range("I" & x).Value
.Fields("UniqueID") = Sheets(user).Range("J" & x).Value
.Fields("Comments") = Sheets(user).Range("K" & x).Value

.Update 'stores the new record
End With

x = x + 1 'next row
Loop

rst.Close

cnn.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

'communicate with the user
MsgBox " The data has been successfully sent to the access database"

'Update the sheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Clear the data
'Sheets(user).Range("A1:K1000").ClearContents
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:

'clear memory
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Export_Data"
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you include the primary key in your query? That is required if you want it to be updatable.

Comment: Hi braX, Yes the primary key is included (UniqueID). Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, `DATA` is a query in the remote accdb. If so, it should be updateable. See, for example this: [Why is my query not updateable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267398/why-is-my-query-not-updateable) for criterias. If this is a table, check if you have read-write rights on accdb and the file has no read-only attribute.

Comment: Sergey,Thanks for the quick response and it is a table, but the accdb has all permissions and file has no read-only attributes.