# MS Access sub-form data entry locked on inserting SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am not able to encode any entries to the Sub-form data grid on the Main form when I inserted the following SQL field. If I remove this column, the system allows me to the new data record creation. Can anyone look into this issue please!

**Advance Payment Balance**:

```
(SELECT SUM(NZ(T1.AdvancePayment,0)-
            NZ(([GrossInv-WorksCertified-61110]*
            [SubCon-BasicInfo].[Advance-409130-%]/100),0)) 
   FROM [InvoiceMaster] AS T1 
  WHERE T1.[SubConName]=[InvoiceMaster].[SubconName] 
    AND T1.[ID]<=[InvoiceMaster].[ID])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using calculations in a query make the underlying recordset not updateable.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267398/why-is-my-query-not-updateable) for an excellent list why queries (and forms based on them) sometimes are not updateable.

The proper way to include calculations on a datasheet form is to open it in design view, add a new text box control to them, and set the controls control source equal to an `=` equal sign followed by your calculation.

You also will need to rewrite the subquery to a domain aggregate or use a combo box to use a query.

Rewrite example:
`DSUM("NZ(InvoiceMaster.AdvancePayment,0)- NZ(([GrossInv-WorksCertified-61110]*[SubCon-BasicInfo].[Advance-409130-%]/100),0)", "InvoiceMaster", "[SubConName] = """ & [InvoiceMaster].[SubconName]  & """ AND ID = " & [InvoiceMaster].[ID])`

Comment: I tried as you advised. But the text box gives me "#Name?" Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: See edit. Perhaps the most simple way is to assign the query to a combo box, and then make sure the combo box selects the first value.

Comment: Well tried your suggestion, but couldn't succeed. Can you please let me know how to select the first value by default.

Comment: See [this page](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/combo-boxes/select-first.html)