# Can I update calculated field in the query

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables. In table1 I have 2 columns like below, `Doc No` is (pk)

```
Doc No                 Title            
--------               -----------
Doc-0001               test-0001
Doc-0002               test-0002
```

In table 2 I also have two columns `Doc No` (pk), `Transmittal` (pk)

```
 Doc No         Transmittal
 --------------------------
 Doc-0001       TT-0001
 Doc-0001       TT-0002
 Doc-0002       TT-1000
```

Now I want to create a form that has 3 fields based on table 1 like below, if I have related record for each Doc No in table2 it shows in the form with ticked check box in the form and when un ticked check box it deleted related records  table2.

I have thought about that with steps like below but I have some doubt:

1. I have to write a query based on table1 and it has a calculated column that returns (0) or (-1) if find related record in table 2.

   ```
   Doc No              title           checkbox
   ```
2. I have to write a before update event for check box of the form for deleting related records in table 2 when untick the checkbox.

My question is about the calculated column in the query. Can I update that?

I mean can I untick that in the form? Or just it is a read only field and I cannot tick or untick that and so event procedure does not work on that?

What is the solution please?

Comment: ms-access is not SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Queries containing calculated fields are not updateable.

See [this questions answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267398/why-is-my-query-not-updateable) by [Johnny Bones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2174085/johnny-bones) for an overview when queries are and aren't updateable.

If you want to use a calculated field in a form, you should not do the calculation in the underlying table, but in the control source of the control you want to have a calculated field on.

However, that still makes the calculated field read-only (the rest of your form won't be, though, in contrast to when you use a calculated field in a query). To solve this, you will need do the calculations you want in VBA, and program the behavior you want when changing the field in VBA.

Example using a VBA approach: (calculated field stores the sum of 2 fields, changing it changes the first field)

```
Public Sub Form_Current()
      MyUnboundTextbox.Value = Field1.Value + Field2.Value
End Sub

Private Sub MyUnboundTextbox_AfterUpdate()
      Field1.Value = MyUnboundTextbox.Value - Field2.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, you mean, i have to put a unbound check box on my form and then by using on current event of form define control source of chebox. and then it will be updatable? if possible please a short code or explain.

Comment: No, if you're using a calculation and want to have it updateable, you need to handle all of it in VBA. See the example.

Comment: thanks a lot, when my form is a continouse form is the same?

Comment: Nope, then it's impossible