# Access Update on Query Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, sql-update, subquery

I'm currently in the process of converting an access database to SQL.  While going through it, I found this.

```
Update EmployeeCustomerOrderDetail set Valid = -1;
```

This is strange because EmployeeCustomerOrderDetail is a query, defined below.

```
Select * 
From Employee 
   inner join Order on Employee.EmployeeID = Order.EmployeeID 
   inner join Customer on Order.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID 
   inner join OrderDetail on Order.OrderID = OrderDetail.OrderID
```

I thought that this achieved nothing since an Update on a Select wouldn't work, but I tested it with

```
Update (Select * From Employees) as Emp set Emp.WorkPhone as 'Random Value'
```

And it worked.

My question then, is how is this processed.  Does the update traverse backwards through all query tables until it finds a dataTable?  Will it change the value of  a reference column, or the actual data in the associated table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works with updateable recordsets. It's the same as just changing a value directly in the Access query.

In an updateable recordsets, each field in the dataset (query) is directly bound to a field in a table. This means updates directly affect the underlying tables of a query. You can review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24269023/7296893) for rules about which recordsets are and aren't updateable.

Another really contra-intuitive thing about this is that recordsets with outer joins can be contain updateable unmatched records. In this case, a record is created in the table that doesn't contain a matched record, then a new one gets created.

Comment: Thanks.  This was really hard to research given that I didn't have the actual terminology.  Great answer