# Update Query - How to fix to avoid "Operation must use an updateable query" message

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE cl INNER JOIN bb ON cl.r_si = bb.si

SET cl.s_si = (SELECT si FROM bb AS y
    WHERE y.si = bb.si+1
    AND 
    (y.p >=bb.p*(1+(bb.imax+y.dmax-((bb.imax-bb.dmax)-((bb.iminn+bb.dminn)-bb.rminn)))/100)
    OR
    y.p<=bb.p*(1+(bb.imin+y.dmin+((bb.imax-bb.dmax)-((bb.iminn+bb.dminn)-bb.rminn)))/100)))

WHERE (((cl.s_si) is null));
```

This returns the message "Operation must use an updateable query"

This is the same query formulated as a SELECT instead of an UPDATE:

```
SELECT

(SELECT si FROM bb AS y
    WHERE y.si = bb.si+1
    AND (y.p>=bb.p*(1+(bb.imax+y.dmax-((bb.imax-bb.dmax)-((bb.iminn+bb.dminn)-bb.rminn)))/100)
    OR
    y.p<=bb.p*(1+(bb.imin+y.dmin+((bb.imax-bb.dmax)-((bb.iminn+bb.dminn)-bb.rminn)))/100))) AS s_si

FROM cl INNER JOIN bb ON cl.r_si = bb.si;
```

The query works in the SELECT formulation. What must I change in the UPDATE query to avoid this error message? It is necessary to update the table cl and not create a new one.

Comment: Check that at least one of the columns used in join  (cl.r_si or bb.si) have a unique index

Comment: Both of these columns have unique indexes.

Comment: `cl` and `bb` are both tables? if bb is a query with aggregation (I see columns dmin and dmax), then the query will be not updateable. Try to replace them by functions `DMin` and `DMax`

Comment: No, there is no aggregation. The names of those columns are the same as those functions by co-incidence.

Comment: Try to check your query using this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/24269023/5339178