# MSAccess UPDATE on INNER JOIN on INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I need some help with an update statement in MS Access.
(The statement was written by a former employee. The SQL statement itself was built automatically through using the graphical editor.)

The full statement:

```
UPDATE   

(((dbo_customer AS c
    INNER JOIN dbo_priceGrpD AS pd
        ON c.Nr = pd.Nr)
        INNER JOIN dbo_priceGrp AS p
            ON p.grp = pd.grp)
            INNER JOIN dbo_customerGrp AS cg
                ON c.grp = cg.grp)

SET k.U2021 = 0
```

It works fine if I remove the second and the third `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE   

dbo_customer AS c
    INNER JOIN dbo_priceGrpD AS pd
        ON c.Nr = pd.Nr

SET k.Umsatz2021 = 0
```

The error from Access on executing the full statement: "Operation must use an updateable query." `(Error 3073)`

Comment: Message is fairly clear. Query is not editable and cannot be used in an UPDATE action. Edit question to show sample data as text tables. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267398/why-is-my-query-not-updateable

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I know. And I also know the problem, why it is not editable. BUT: Why the hack is msaccess building this sql query, when I build the updates through the graphical interface?
Is there a way I can alterate the given sql query so it would go without errors?

Comment: Edit question to show raw data and desired result as text tables. Query builder only builds query you tell it to build. We don't know your database. Why would you need to pull data from all these tables to update Customer record(s)? Query references an alias table name "k" in the SET clause but I don't see any "k" name in the joins. I am surprised even the second SQL works.