# Multi-Table Query Not Updateable in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

First post for me so please bear with me if I'm short on providing enough info.

I'm trying to put a query together that will be used as a subform on a project expense data entry form. As part of the query I want Access to pull the correct tax rates to calculate PST & GST correctly in calculated fields within the query. I have a query that consists of 5 tables:

1. tblProjectExpenseLineItems (PK: ExpenseLineItemID, FK: ProjectExpenseID)
2. tblProjectExpenses         (PK: ProjectExpenseID, FK: ProjectNoID)
3. tblProjects                (PK: ProjectNoID, FK: ClientID)
4. tblClientList              (PK: Client ID)
5. tblTaxRate

Query design looks like this: [qryProjectExpensesLineItemsExtended Query Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDAGU.png)

The picture doesn't show it but the PSTTaxRate field is set to [tblTaxRate]![TaxRate] and the PST field is just the PST calculation on the expense line item.

I manually joined [tblClientList].[Province] to [tblTaxRate].[TaxJurisdiction]. These aren't related in the database relationships since neither fields are primary keys and I get the "indeterminate" relationship type. I have checked and confirmed that the values in these fields are in fact the same so results do show when I run the query.

The query fields are primarily from the tblProjectsExpensesLineItems table only since this is the table I want to update through the subform (I've tried adding the different PKs to see if that would change anything but no such luck). The only reason I have the other four tables is to get the [tblClientList].[Province] field so that I can pick up the location of the client and know which tax to charge. Where I live we've had our PST change a few times recently so I further filter the query using the [ExpenseDate] field to find the tax rate that fits between the [tblTaxRate].[StartDate] and [tblTaxRate].[EndDate] fields.

Things I've checked/read into:

- I've checked that the table relationships have been set, are related to primary keys, and have "Enforce Referential Integrity" checked.
- I've tried deleting tblTaxRate out of the query since it doesn't have an actual relationship. The query still isn't updateable and Access prompts me for the TaxRate, StartDate and EndDate fields when I run the query
- I found a very detailed post here [Why is my query not updateable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267398/why-is-my-query-not-updateable/24269023) about reasons why queries aren't updateable. I'm pretty new to Access so I was able to rule out most of them, but some of them I don't quite understand (maybe something to do with the one-to-many and many-to-one relationships?)
- Deleting all the tables except for the one I want to update. This of course makes the query updateable but Access prompts me for all the fields related to trying to find the tax rate.

I thought maybe an easy way out is to just manually enter tax rates but the database is being used for invoicing so I'm trying to eliminate potential for user input error.

I also thought this would be easier if I used form controls to do the heavy lifting but the tax calcs show up in many forms so I was hoping to keep the calcs at the query level so that I don't have to keep writing the calcs for every form and instead just reference the same query.

I'm at a total loss. I have the query responding properly but I can't do any data entry which is the sole purpose of the query! Any help is much appreciated!!

Scott

Comment: Simplify. Bind form to table, not a complex query. Review https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=83304. And link on PK/FK fields. If you aren't saving TaxRateID into related table as FK then don't define it as PK, TaxJurisdiction should be PK.

Comment: Do you really need to show tax calcs in data entry forms? This sort of data manipulation is best done in reports.

Comment: My first go at this I bound the subform to a table and it worked fine when hard coding the tax rates. Its when I try to get the tax rates into a query from a table so that they're not hard coded is when I started having this problem. I wanted to show the tax calcs on the form because we're still old fashioned and have hard copy expense claims that need to be manually entered. The data entry form doubles as a manual verification that everything is entered correct.

Comment: My POV. You still need to simplify query. It is too complex because, as you already noted, of the relationships. Find other means to pull in tax info for calcs. The link I provided showed using multi-column combobox instead of including table. Maybe you will need DLookup domain aggregate function.

Comment: The reason why SQL see the query as not updateable may because of left and right joins so you can not be sure exactly which records it is supposed to update. It may be useful to separate your queries into read only for display and then use a separate query for update called from your update button.

Comment: thanks everyone. I opted to keep the "read only" query for displaying records and made a simplified query for data entry.